# How do I assign with square brackets in R?

Tags: r

I have the following problem. I want to assign with square brackets, but the assign function won't let me do it. The following code is an example from the R documentation for the assign function.

```
a <- 1:4
assign("a[1]", 2)
a[1] == 2          # FALSE
get("a[1]") == 2   # TRUE
```

I want to access a[1] so that a[1] == 2 becomes TRUE. Instead, the assign function creates an object called "a[1]". How do I fix this problem? Are there alternatives? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You must `assign` the whole object or none of it, there is no notion of `[` or `[[` or `$` within the `x=` argument of `assign` (and `get`). You can use `assign("a", replace(get("a"), 1, 2))`. (Side note: usually the use of `get`/`assign` is either not required or another mechanism is far better.)

Comment: Cannot you just assign by simply doing ```a[1] <- 2```

Comment: From the help page ?assign :  assign does not dispatch assignment methods, so it cannot be used to set elements of vectors, names, attributes, etc.

Comment: R translates `a[1] <- 2` to ```a <- `[<-`(a, 1, 2)``` . So, you teorethically could do: ```assign("a",  `[<-`(a, 1, 2))```

Comment: You should never use `assign` unless you understand environments and need to assign into a specific environment. It's probably best if you forget that this function exists for now.